# Remove all similar field from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a problem, as I messed up earlier in my work. I have Model named "xxx", and I have the following fields

```
:identity, :lat, :lon, :name, :tag, :some_id
```

I would like to remove all rows which have same

```
:identity
```

so for example if I had

```
{identity = "2348", name = "Mr. Jackson"}
{identity = "2348", name = "Mr. Jackson"}
```

I would like to have only

```
{identity = "2348", name = "Mr. Jackson"}
```

(I should have put validator before transferring lots of data). But How would one achieve this ?

I'm thinking of writing some method in Model and then calling it from my console. How would one solve this ?

There might be a multiple cases of described scenarios.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve that with the following SQL query (works for sqlite and postgresql):

```
DELETE FROM xxx WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT min(id) FROM xxx GROUP BY identity);
```

Don't forget to take a copy of the database before doing it, so if anything goes wrong, you can try again.

A little explanation of what that query exactly does:

```
SELECT min(id) FROM xxx GROUP BY identity
```

First it groups the records by identity, i.e a record and its duplicates. Then for each group, it gives you the record with the lowest id, the one you want to keep.

```
DELETE FROM xxx WHERE id NOT IN ()
```

It deletes all record with an id that is not in the set of ids provided by the select. It then deletes all the duplicates.

Comment: what does this command do ? I presume, it will loop through all rows ?

Comment: @qweVar I've updated my answer with some explanations. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks man, i think I get it, but you would execute this in rails dbconsole

Comment: @qweVar yep, rails dbconsole

Comment: Thanks man :) Really helped. Now your name is one of the method in my app. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Create another table with the contraint required `primary key (id)`, then

```
insert into yyy (select * from xxx);
```

and ignore the errors.  This will allow you to keep a copy of the original data, in case you ever need to access it again.